# Can I use the visa in my expired passport when my new passport is in a different name?

Tags: visas, passports, passport-renewals

I live in the UK. I have two passports: an expired one which has a visa that is valid for 3 more years. On my new passport, there is no visa, but the name is different as I recently changed my name by deed poll.

Is it still okay to travel using both passports and carrying the deed poll certificate. as well?

Comment: What country issued the visa?

Comment: And what is your nationality?

Comment: My nationality is indian and I am living in UK . I got this EEA spouse visa from uk

Comment: Are these UK passports?

Answer (score 2):

You most likely have to update the details on your visa. I am from Mexico and live in the UK. I have a biometric visa (it is a card, no longer on the passport). I moved house in December and I had 90 days to update my address or I could face a fine. If I would have changed my name as well then I would have had to apply and pay for an updated visa (not a new one, but an updated one).

This will help:
https://www.gov.uk/change-circumstances-visa-brp/youre-in-the-uk-and-dont-have-a-brp

Comment: Hi Thank you for this but when u go on the gov.co.UK and type transfer your visa . they say you don't need to transfer your visa just carry both passport for travel . what do you think . Shall I still need to transfer my visa to the new one.

Comment: For peace of mind I would do a last attempt at finding out with more clarity. Try calling the Citizens Advice Bureau or call any immigration lawyer as for them it might just be a real easy question to answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about UK visa, then the answer is that you should be fine, although it could make travel easier if you update/change details on your visa.  I am speaking from experience.

When my wife and I got married, we both lived in the UK; I had a USA passport with an HSMP visa (then-equivalent of Tier 1 General) and my wife had a Russian passport with a Work Permit visa (then-equivalent of Tier 2).  After we got married, she changed her name and got a new Russian passport showing her new name.  After that, whenever she had to travel internationally, she would carry her old (cancelled) Russian passport with the visa, her new Russian passport and a copy of the marriage certificate (we got married in the USA).  Not once has she had any problems entering the UK. This continued for about a year until she got her spouse visa in her new name in her new passport.

Depending on visa type, you may have had to register with a local police department.  If this is the case, you must notify the local police department of the change of name (and this was the case with my wife, too) - but you still are not required to get a new visa.

It is important to carry with you both, old and new, passports and some sort of an official document confirming the change of your name (marriage certificate, court ruling, deed poll, etc.)